# SVGs in JSSX : enable-background

Tags: reactjs, svg, jsx

Im using react, Trying to convert an SVG to jsx and all seems pretty well however all of my svgs have an enable-background property

```
style="enable-background:new 0 0 473.806 473.806;"
```

Which im having trouble converting to JSX
Im currently using

```
style={{enableBackground:'new 0 0 387.2 387.2'}}
```

Which doesnt work, I would just use an img tag however i want to change the color of the SVG on hover.

Update: heres the SVG

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 16.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" id="Capa_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="35px" height="35px" viewBox="0 0 35 35" style="enable-background:new 0 0 35 35;" xml:space="preserve">
<g>
    <path d="M25.302,0H9.698c-1.3,0-2.364,1.063-2.364,2.364v30.271C7.334,33.936,8.398,35,9.698,35h15.604
        c1.3,0,2.364-1.062,2.364-2.364V2.364C27.666,1.063,26.602,0,25.302,0z M15.004,1.704h4.992c0.158,0,0.286,0.128,0.286,0.287
        c0,0.158-0.128,0.286-0.286,0.286h-4.992c-0.158,0-0.286-0.128-0.286-0.286C14.718,1.832,14.846,1.704,15.004,1.704z M17.5,33.818
        c-0.653,0-1.182-0.529-1.182-1.183s0.529-1.182,1.182-1.182s1.182,0.528,1.182,1.182S18.153,33.818,17.5,33.818z M26.021,30.625
        H8.979V3.749h17.042V30.625z"/>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: enable-background does nothing in any modern browser. Why do you think you can use it to change the color of an SVG on hover?

Comment: This doesnt change the color - But the SVG does not show when i remove it

Comment: We'd need a [mcve] here because as I said all browsers ignore this.

Comment: Updated with the SVG im trying to use

Answer (score 0):

Removing the `style="enable-background..."` works fine.  See below.

If yours fails, then you are doing something else wrong somewhere.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 16.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" id="Capa_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="35px" height="35px" viewBox="0 0 35 35" xml:space="preserve">
<g>
    <path d="M25.302,0H9.698c-1.3,0-2.364,1.063-2.364,2.364v30.271C7.334,33.936,8.398,35,9.698,35h15.604
        c1.3,0,2.364-1.062,2.364-2.364V2.364C27.666,1.063,26.602,0,25.302,0z M15.004,1.704h4.992c0.158,0,0.286,0.128,0.286,0.287
        c0,0.158-0.128,0.286-0.286,0.286h-4.992c-0.158,0-0.286-0.128-0.286-0.286C14.718,1.832,14.846,1.704,15.004,1.704z M17.5,33.818
        c-0.653,0-1.182-0.529-1.182-1.183s0.529-1.182,1.182-1.182s1.182,0.528,1.182,1.182S18.153,33.818,17.5,33.818z M26.021,30.625
        H8.979V3.749h17.042V30.625z"/>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thats not a react component though nor are you using JSX

Comment: I was just responding to your comment that "the SVG doesn't show when I remove it".

Comment: Ok. Then the problem is your React code, not the SVG.  We can't diagnose code we can't see.  Please update your question with a [mcve].